# php require_once file with 5000 lines vs smaller require_once files

Tags: php, memcached, require-once

I have read so many different answers on this topic. The more i search more diverse it gets.
I have a single require_once file with all my site functions but this has grown to 5000 lines. Is it time for me to break it up and is it performance efficient to do it this way?
At the moment each page is obviously having to traverse multiple lines for which it will not use.

I have also heard about apc and memcache. Are there any significant issues with these options?

Hope someone can clarify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should organize your include files by so that unrelated functions are in different files, and then an application can include the ones that it needs.

Your question about apc and memcache is not very clear -- what kinds of issues are you concerned with? Anyway, you should not put unrelated questions in the same post. And general questions like "are there issues" are not really appropriate on SO. This is for specific programming problems -- you post code that's not working and people help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks, it is related to this as i am trying to optimise my site speed. I was just wondering whether the implementation of memcache or apc are worth the change. My scripts could do with being faster but not at the expense of having new issues.